# Excel How do you get the value of a cell via another cell?

Tags: excel

This may be a really dumb question.

In Col A, I have a column of values. In Col J, I have the row number of the values in Col A that I want. How do I use this to get the values?

For example

**Col A**

row 1: bob

row 2: joe

row 3: apple

row 4: tom

row 5: tim

**Col B**

1

4

5

In another column, I basically want:

bob

tom

tim

I have about 300 of these values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`INDEX`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd?CorrelationId=2a9ed1aa-a8cc-4d59-84de-83bfd2ea523f&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HP010342608) function for this. Given columns A and B as you defined, you can put `=INDEX(A1:A5,B1)` in another column. That says to index (look up in) the array `A1:A5` with the pointer in cell `B1`. Since `B1` has the value 1, this is equivalent to `=INDEX(A1:A5,1)`, and returns "bob".

If you want to copy that to multiple cells, make sure you keep the array (`A1:A5`) part constant, and just change the cell reference (`B1`). Your formulas would then be `=INDEX(A$1:A$5,B1)`, `=INDEX(A$1:A$5,B2)`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Index () worksheet function.

Answer (score 0):

If these were in 3 columns with headings, such that under some heading, say "names" in A2 would be "bob" with other names below; and under another heading, say "row" in B2 would be 1, with other numbers below, then, under some 3rd heading, say "result":

```
In C2, copied down
=OFFSET(A1,B2,0)
```

Comment: Although technically correct, volatile functions such as `OFFSET` and `INDIRECT` should be avoided if at all possible. As the other answers have indicated, `INDEX` is a much better alternative. In my experience, `INDIRECT` can *almost* always be avoided (only unavoidable when doing some weird complex cross-referencing between sheets) and I've never found an instance where I had to use `OFFSET`.

Comment: Good point. For OP/readers, volatile means whenever there is any change in your workbook, the offset formula is recalculated, keeping excel busy longer. This is not an issue in a small workbook, but can be an issue in a large one. Thus, other answers may be preferable. What is not clear to me - another user can surely answer - is whether a non-volatile solution may result in a cell not updating when a cell is modified that should make it change.

Comment: I tend to think of volatile vs. NV in terms of dependencies. NV functions know what their dependencies are, so they can avoid being recalculated if its dependencies aren't changed. As opposed to volatile functions which don't know what their dependencies are, so all volatile functions must be recalculated whenever any single change is made in the worksheet, regardless of whether or not it actually has anything to do with those volatile functions. In other words: Non-volatile functions will update **only** when necessary. Never heard of a non-volatile function not updating when it should have.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the indirect function to accomplish that:

for example in column c you cou use the formula:

```
=INDIRECT("A" & B2, TRUE)
```

This would take the row number in your cell B2 and get the value in the A column.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Although technically correct, volatile functions such as `OFFSET` and `INDIRECT` should be avoided if at all possible. As the other answers have indicated, `INDEX` is a much better alternative. In my experience, `INDIRECT` can almost always be avoided (only unavoidable when doing some weird complex cross-referencing between sheets) and I've never found an instance where I had to use `OFFSET`.

Comment: Thank you for this piece of technical information, I didn't think of the impact in really big files.

Comment: It usually is a negligible difference for smaller spreadsheets, but for larger spreadsheets the difference can be literally less than a second calculation times to minutes of calculation times.